# how to create UILayoutGuide in interface builder?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a `UILayoutGuide` in Interface Builder. I can create `UILayoutGuide` in code. I am using **Xcode 7 beta**.

How can I create a `UILayoutGuide`  in Interface Builder?

Comment: I watched them . I did not saw lecture where UILayoutGuide is created in Interface Builder.

Comment: The video Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 2 discusses layout guides about 1/2 way through. They never talk about how to create them in IB. 

Comment: One thing that doesn't work is adding a view to the hierarchy then changing it's class in IB to UILayoutGuide. UILayoutGuide doesn't have superview property, so instantiating a UILayoutGuide by trying to trick IB doesn't work.

Comment: @Poql, no. The 219 session at WWDC 2015 does not show how to use UILayoutGuide in IB.  According to Apple on the official dev discussion forum, NS/UILayoutGuide is not supported in Interface Builder.  I guess we have to continue using dummy UIViews for now, at least in IB.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`UILayoutGuide` is not available from Interface Builder yet.  Please file a radar at https://bugreport.apple.com to request that Apple add support.

Comment: It's crazy that we would even have to file a bug report for a feature which is so obviously needed in Interface Builder.  But then, that's Auto Layout in a nutshell...

Comment: still not available at XCode 9

Comment: Xcode 10.0 beta (10L176w) STILL NOT... this is a joke. aaaand again adding some stupid hidden spacer views -.-

Comment: Yeah, they have more of their built-in guides exposed, but not ones we can create. Maybe that's positive progress...